# Main class will not create client's automatically

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I am creating a game of top trumps and in it I create a server and two clients. I have a controller class that I want to use to control the game. When I run the controller it creates my Server but I have to run the clients separate to create them.

Is there a way that when I run the controller it launches my clients as well as my servers? I am a beginner when it comes to client/server in java so any help would be great.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        //Empty card arrays for now while testing
        Cards[] Player1 = new Cards[2];
        Cards[] Player2 = new Cards[2];

        Server server = new Server();

        Client client = new Client(Player1, "Gary");
        Client client2 = new Client(Player2, "Jack");
    }
}



 public class Server {


    public Server() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
        System.out.println("Connecting....");

        while(!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //Reads my card object
            Cards card = (Cards)ois.readObject();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(600, 600);
            //Test
            JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(card.image); 
            frame.add(imageLabel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(card.name);
            ois.close();
            socket.close();         

        }
    }
}



 public class Client implements Serializable{   


    public Client(Cards[] hand, String string) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3000);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        //This is a test to show my card object can be passed over the stream
        Cards card = new Cards(string, 9, 5, 3, 5,new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\gary.kelly\\Pictures\\Cards\\John Snow.jpg"));  
        oos.writeObject(card);   
        oos.close();
        socket.close();       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is single threaded now, server's accept method blocks main thread, so clients can't connect. You can start server and clients in different threads to run them together in one java process.

```
    new Thread(() -> new Server()).start();
    new Thread(() -> new Client(Player1, "Gary")).start();
    new Thread(() -> new Client(Player2, "Jack")).start();
```